# Binding to a VPN interface not working

Tags: vpn, raspbian, route, ppp, transmission

so I've been working on setting up a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian lately, and I have almost everything set up the way I want. I plan on using it headless, but I've been using X11 forwarding to view guis when I need to. I have transmission-daemon running, the remote gui accessable from outside my network, and a webserver running that I can access as well.

I got a VPN, and I would like to just send my transmission traffic (not the gui traffic, since you can specify that in settings.json for transmission-daemon) over the VPN. I set my VPN settings in nm-connection-editor to "use this connection only for resources on its network", so I could still browse the web and such using my eth0 interface. When I connect to my vpn, it gives me a ppp0 interface, since its a VPN using ppp0, and when I connect my transmission daemon to that interface, nothing happens. No torrents load. Can someone help?

I figure I need to change the routing tables of my Pi, but I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Here are my routing tables.

Pre-VPN:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         DD-WRT          0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

After-VPN (used only for resources on its network):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.4.0.1        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
37.48.66.67     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
37.48.66.67     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

After VPN (option disabled):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.4.0.1        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
37.48.66.67     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
37.48.66.67     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

If I don't enable the option, all traffic on my Pi goes over the VPN as normal, and transmission works correctly.